# How to convert following hibernate annotaion to JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
 <map name="urls" lazy="false">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
        <key column="EMP_ID"/>
        <map-key column="EMP_URL_TYPE_ID" type="int"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.employee.ems.EMSURL"/>
 </map>
```

where Primary Key of EMP Table is "EMP_ID" and

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In EMP entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="emp",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKey(name="empUrlTypeId")
private Map<Integer,EMSURL> urls
```

In EMSURL entity:

```
@Id
private Integer empUrlTypeId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")
private EMP emp;
```

name = "urls" corresponds to the name of the property of the entity where the collection is defined, lazy false implies that the relationship is defined as EAGER, as oneToMany is the PK is in the target entity, so we define the relationship in the EMSURL entity and in EMS we establish a bidirectional relationship through mapping, the Integer type in the object is not mapped, since when modeling the JPA entities the name of the column is indicated in the @JoinColumn annotation but the type is that of the own entity.

Comment: need to assign to MAP object like follows
private Map<String, EMSURL> properties;

Comment: Thanks for the solution. As this is a bidirectional relationship i have found a solution for unidirectional mapping to cater my requirement

Comment: Perfect but reconsider making it bidirectional if possible since later it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

In EMP entity:

```
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")
 @MapKey(name="empUrlType")
 private Map<Integer,EMSURL> urls
```

In EMSURL entity:

```
  @JoinColumn(name="EMP_URL_TYPE_ID")
  private String empUrlType;
```